# Can't create add a SQL Server user: The login already has an account under a different user name

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

Environment:

- SQL Server 2005 Express
- Windows 7

When I installed SQL Server, I followed the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905868.aspx to set my computer's admin account as the SQL Server admin.

However, when I try to access a database on my computer through Visual Studio 2008, I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The database 'Parkinsons' does not exist or you do not have permission to see it.



Would you like to attempt to create it?
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

Then, if I go to SQL Server and add a user to that database, I get the following error message:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express
------------------------------

Create failed for User 'zian'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.2047.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+User&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

The login already has an account under a different user name. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15063)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.4053&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=15063&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

1. Why doesn't VS piggy back on the dbo account?
2. If the dbo account is unusable, then why won't SQL Server let me make an account so that I can access my own data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this database already exist? If so you'll have to refer to it as dbo.Parkisins Or whatever user schema was used to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Visual Studio as administrator. On my Server 2008 box, my user (which is a local administrator and a sysadmin on the DB) cannot connect using SQL Management Studio unless I run the Management Studio as administrator.